# Fullcalendar - 3 day view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js and want to build a view that shows whole months but only 3 days per row for mobile devices.

I know that I can make my own view like this:

```
views: {
  monthThreeDays: {
    type: 'month',
    duration: { days: 3 }
  },
  defaultView: 'monthThreeDays'
}
```

But this will show only 3 days of the month and change the prev/next buttons to only switch to the prev/next 3 days.

Is there a way to achieve having rows with only 3 days in it but for the whole month?

Edit:
Because it was unclear, here's a visualization of what i want to achieve:

Mobile View:

[image: Mobile View]

Desktop View:
[image: Desktop View]

Comment: "Duration", as you have discovered, specifies how long the whole view is, not how many days are in each row. So that option is no help to you.

Comment: " having rows with only 3 days in it but for the whole month"...so you mean first row is 1st, 2nd 3rd of the month (say they fall on Tues Wed Thu for example), then the next row is 4th 5th 6th of the month (so they'd be Fri Sat Sun)? That sounds like it would be very hard for the user to figure out what they are looking at. People are used to seeing all the Mondays in one column, for example. Or do you mean only show those days within the month which fall on 3 specific weekdays (e.g only show all the Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays within a given month)? It's not clear what your requirement is.

Comment: I edited my question with two images showing what i want to achieve to make it more clear.

Comment: ok well the desktop view looks pretty much like the standard month view, so that doesn't seem to require much work, if any. However fullCalendar doesn't really support mobile view or a flexible grid - it's based on a very rigid grid layout system using tables overlaid on top of each other. To get what you're looking for you would probably need to make a totally custom view - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js . This is a lot of work and not a simple task, too big a scope for anyone to answer it on here, certainly. Consider carefully if you _really_ need this feature or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I really need this feature because I have to display more info than just the date, so on mobile it would get too narrow. If it isn't realizable with fullcalender, could you recommend any other calendar plugin that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: No I'm not familiar with anything specific, and anyway giving recommendations is off-topic (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'll have to do some research.

Comment: Another alternative on mobile is just to use the fullCalendar "list" view (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view), which IMHO is more usable than your layout - as I mentioned before, people don't think of their week in 3-day chunks - it's hard to see the start and end of a given week (because obviously a week is 7 days, so the end of each week will fall in a different column in the grid.). There is a built-in "listMonth" view you can use out of the box.

Comment: The design is already agreed on with the customer, I can't change it since I'm only the guy who has to implement it. I would have chosen the list view if I had the chance. Thanks for your advice, but I will now build with CLNDR.js, which makes it pretty easy to achieve the desired design.